# 502 Bad Gateway Error - exited on signal 11

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm

I have an issue on a particular Magento store, on two different servers.

The issue is that when I save admin panels, I get a 502 error. The values actually save to the database, as pressing back on the browser loads the admin page with the new values set. However, the page will always hit 502 instead of refreshing after the save, and pressing back manually is the only way to continue working.

Log files show the following:

**/var/log/php5-fpm.log**

```
exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 3.555010 seconds from start
```

**/var/log/nginx/website_dev_error.log**

```
[error] 38501#0: *625 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

**pool file variables**

```
[website.dev]
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.website.dev.sock

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660

pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 2
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 2
pm.process_idle_timeout = 60s

php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 2048M
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 600
```

At the moment, the pool settings are amended. I increased the memory limit to 2GB, and the process_idle_timeout to 60s (from 5s) but this hasn't helped.

Some information about the environment:

**os version**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:        15.10
Codename:       wily
```

**php version**

```
PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1 (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

**nginx version**

```
nginx version: nginx/1.9.3 (Ubuntu)
```

Any advice would be very welcome,